# How to do a category blog override in Joomla 3?

Tags: php, joomla, overriding

What I am wanting to do is edit my category blog layout so that:

1. The description to be limited to x amount of characters (on the
   fly without having to insert a read more break in the article)
2. Remove all formatting from the article text.

Then when the full article is opened all the full text and formatting is present.

Could someone please tell me which files I need to modify/duplicate please, would really appreciate it explained as simply as possible as this is the first time I have dove into overrides :)

I have created an overwrite of the file blog_item.php using the built in function within my template section within joomla but the contents of this file are:

```
   <?php
   /**
   * @package   yoo_master2
   * @author    YOOtheme http://www.yootheme.com
   * @copyright Copyright (C) YOOtheme GmbH
   * @license   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU/GPL
   */

   // include config and layout
   $base = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
   include($base.'/config.php');
   include($warp['path']->path('layouts:'.preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($base, '/').'/', '', __FILE__, 1)));
```

is it just pointing the script to the original joomla file for blog_item.php?

Thanks
Luke

Comment: You need to look at the parts that are managing individual items, not the container. What you want to truncate is `$this->item->introtext`  There is a method that that will truncate by character count. Look in mod_articles_category, it shows how to use it.

Comment: ok thank you very much, i will have a play around with it. One last question how do i modify it so that when i do an update i wont lose my changes? cheers

Comment: ok so i have had a look in the mod_articles_category file but nothing i change in there effects the outcome of my blog layout? any ideas please many thanks

Comment: YOu should NEVER modify the original file. COPY the file to your template's html folder to `/content/category`  ... you can do this automatically in the template IDE that is part of the template manager in Joomla.  However, probably this is actually in a JLayout file and then what you need to do, also in the template manager, is instead copy the relevant layout file.

Comment: ok mate thanks will let you know how i get on :)

Answer (score 0):

In the administrator,

1. go to Template Manager, Templates and click on the name of the template you are using.
2. Go to the Create Overrides tab.
3. Under components, select com_content> category
4. Under layouts, select content
5. Go to the editor tab.
6. Under html, com_content select `blog_item.php`
7. Around line 47 you will see `<?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>`
8. Wrap that in the string truncation method.

Comment: have edited my question mate as the file you said about contains very little info (please see original post for its contents) thanks

Comment: Notice ` @author    YOOtheme http://www.yootheme.com`  This is not Joomla and you need to  go to the Yootheme website and ask them for support.

Comment: turns out my supscription has expired with Yootheme and i will have to renew it to get support :( will ask another question on here which is more specific to Yootheme i think see if anyone is familiar with it. Cheers again!